# What is meant by 'Transactional Updates'

Tags: ubuntu-core

What is meant by 'transactionally updated' system and how does such an update process different from a 'normally' updated system? What are its advantages/disadvantages?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A "transactional update" is a kind of update that:

- is atomic -- while the update is running, your system is perfectly functioning;
- can be rolled back -- if the upgrade fails or if the newer software version is not compatible with your infrastructure, you can quickly restore the situation as it was before the upgrade.

With APT, generally only the latest version of a software is available (you can't roll back) and upgrading a package with all its dependencies may leave the system temporarily unusable during the process.

In addition, Snappy packages are "self-contained", that is: they have no dependencies. All the libraries and the components needed are bounded inside the same Snappy package.

Comment: Aren't the other OSs [mentioned by Docker](https://blog.docker.com/2015/02/the-new-minimalist-operating-systems/) also transactional? Atomic and CoreOS? Also, to what extent can mobile OSs like Android or iOS be said to be transactional, given that their apps are also self-contained in terms of dependencies?

Comment: Why can't `.deb` packages be installed transactionally as well?

Comment: 2. [NixOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NixOS) seems to meet these criteria.

Comment: That self contained is a very clever idea. You mean when I write a qt5 program and I install it, the snap will contain all the qt5 libraries ? And then someone else write a qt5 program, his snap contain the whole Qt5 empire again ? Fantasctic idea !!! Simply genious.

Comment: And we should follow this "self-contained" principle with the executables also !!! Guys don't link dynamic libraries anymore because that executable will depend on an external dynamic library. Link statically everything !! The executable will be self-contained. Dynamic libraries are already obsolete in these modern times !! The future is static !!! Wooot !!!

Comment: 3. I don't wanna be sarcastic, but not many original ubuntu packages do exist neither. Almost all of them comes from Debian.  If Debian don't create snaps, there will be no snaps. But Debian system engineers are not interested in Snappy. They are so silly, they are struggling with dynamic libraries and dependencies, jeez !!